# how to put two pictures together using minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I wish to put two pictures side by side using mini page, however, it seems the two pictures even not in the same borderline.
[image]

Here is my code, I can not figure out what the problem is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}[H]
\tikzset{
  my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 2em, minimum height=1em},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm]
\node[my box,align=center](s1){$S_1$};
\node[my box,align=center,right = of s1](s2){$S_2$};
\draw[->] (s1)--(s2);
\node[align=center,right = 2mm of s2](s){...};
\node[my box,align=center,right = 2mm of s](s3){$S_n$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\label{Before POR}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\tikzset{
  my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 2em, minimum height=1em},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm]
\node[my box,align=center](s1){$S_1$};
\node[draw,circle,left = of s1](start){};
\draw[->] (start)--(s1);
\node[draw,diamond,right = of s1](end){};
\draw[->] (s1)--(end);
\draw[->] (end) --++ (0em,1.5em) -| (start);
\node[align=center,above = 1.0em of s1](l){k};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\label{After POR}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to avoid to use `minipage`. The environment `tikzpicture` produces a box (Tex's box) and it's possible to place boxes like you want with different tools (baseline,...) you can control the size of the box with `useasboundingbox` for example. The environment `minipage` is interesting if you need to place a paragraph side by side with a picture 
A solution to your problem can be perhaps :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
    \tikzset{
      my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 2em, minimum height=1em},
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm]
\node[my box,align=center](s1){$S_1$};
\node[my box,align=center,right = of s1](s2){$S_2$};
\draw[->] (s1)--(s2);
\node[align=center,right = 2mm of s2](s){...};
\node[my box,align=center,right = 2mm of s](s3){$S_n$};
\node[below] at (current bounding box.south) {label fig one};
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4mm]
\node[my box,align=center](s1){$S_1$};
\node[draw,circle,left = of s1](start){};
\draw[->] (start)--(s1);
\node[draw,diamond,right = of s1](end){};
\draw[->] (s1)--(end);
\draw[->] (end) --++ (0em,1.5em) -| (start);
\node[align=center,above = 1.0em of s1](l){k};
\node[below] at (current bounding box.south) {label fig two};
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{\fill}
\caption{Two figures side by-side}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If necessary you can control the width of each picture.

The boxes are in this case aligned by the bottom but is very easy with `baseline`to place each box relatively to the baseline. You can also place the second picture relatively to the first with the use of named node.

[image]

Comment: it seems to that is better to use the package "here" and the option  "H"
\begin{figure}[H]

Comment: @rpapa Not really sure. I think `H` is an option for the `float` package ( `float` is a fine package perhaps indispensable). H is for <Here, always>, sometimes you get a lot of blank in the page . A possibility for example is to use `h` <here, if possible> or `ht` <here or top of the next page if not possible>. Not sure there is an unique way to get a good result.

Comment: actually I commented too fast, I did not realize you had deleted the minipage.